# Use a mysql connection across my express js app

Tags: javascript, mysql, express

I am pretty new with node.js and express so bear with me please.

I am wondering how i can get a mysql instance and use it in my controller. I have 4 files that look like this:

see my comment in the controller.js file

server.js :

```
var express = require('./config/express');
var app = express();
module.exports = app;
app.listen(3000);
console.log('server running');
```

express.js :

```
var express = require('express'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
mysql = require('mysql');

module.exports = function() {
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.set('views','./app/views');
app.set('view engine','ejs');

//NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE OR WHERE TO PUT THE CONNECTION DETAILS

var dbConnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'someuser',
    database : 'somedb',
    password : 'somepass'
});

//connection.connect();
//
//connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
//    if (err) throw err;
//    console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);
//});
//
//connection.end();


require('../app/routes/index.server.routes.js')(app);

app.use(express.static('./public'));
return app;
};
```

routes.js :

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  var index = require('../controllers/index.server.controller');
  app.get('/', index.render);
  app.post('/', index.stuff);
};
```

controller.js :

```
 exports.render = function(req, res) {
   //DO DB STUFF HERE

   res.render('index', {
     title: 'this is the title'
   });
 };

exports.stuff = function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'this is the title post'
  });
};
```

Comment: Is the goal here to get going with node.js and set up a DBMS? Or do you have to use mysql?

Comment: So you're attaching to some already existing data source?

Comment: This may or may not help. http://www.sitepoint.com/using-node-mysql-javascript-client/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the connection instance in your controller, you'll need to pass it from the express.js file to the controller.js file. The first step is to pass the connection instance to the router:

**express.js**

```
require('../app/routes/index.server.routes.js')(app, connection);
```

This will make it available in the routes.js file. You then need to pass the same connection instance to the controller.

**index.server.routes.js**

```
module.exports = function(app, connection) {
  var index = require('../controllers/index.server.controller')(connection);
  app.get('/', index.render);
  app.post('/', index.stuff);
};
```

The controller will need to be refactored so it takes a connection instance as an argument:

**index.server.controller.js**

```
function IndexController(connection) {
    controllerMethods = {};
    controllerMethods.render = function (req, res) {
        // You can use the connection instance here.
        connection.connect()
        // Run your query
        connection.end()
        ...
    };

    // Define other methods for the controller

    // Return the object that holds the methods.
    return controllerMethods;
}

module.exports = IndexController;
```

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I was looking for thank you so much! One more question if you don't mind, is it a good idea to do db connections in your controller?  One would think they should go to the model.  If so, could you provide an example of how the model and controller interact with each other?

Comment: It is not a good idea to use db connections in your controller. I'll link an example as soon as I can.